# MyBlogLog and OpenId

Tags: support, openid, yahoo

I used to use my yahoo openid to login with stackoverflow.com

The account was associated with the following openid

www.mybloglog.com/buzz/members/laurentschneider

Now when I login to stackoverflow, it generates errors

1) Login

2) Login with Yahoo!

> Unable to log in with your OpenID
>   provider:
>
> The OpenID Provider issued an
>   assertion for an Identifier whose
>   discovery information did not match.
>   Assertion endpoint info:
>   ClaimedIdentifier:
>   http//www.mybloglog.com/buzz/members/laurentschneider#35c03
>   ProviderLocalIdentifier:
>   http//www.mybloglog.com/buzz/members/laurentschneider
>   ProviderEndpoint:
>   https//open.login.yahooapis.com/openid/op/auth
>   OpenID version: 2.0 Service Type URIs:
>   Discovered endpoint info: [{
>   ClaimedIdentifier:
>   http//specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select
>   ProviderLocalIdentifier:
>   http//specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select
>   ProviderEndpoint:
>   https//open.login.yahooapis.com/openid/op/auth
>   OpenID version: 2.0 Service Type URIs:
>   http//specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/server
>   http//specs.openid.net/extensions/pape/1.0
>   http//openid.net/srv/ax/1.0
>   http//specs.openid.net/extensions/oauth/1.0
>   http//specs.openid.net/extensions/ui/1.0/lang-pref
>   http//specs.openid.net/extensions/ui/1.0/mode/popup
>   http//schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/privatepersonalidentifier
>   http//www.idmanagement.gov/schema/2009/05/icam/no-pii.pdf
>   http//www.idmanagement.gov/schema/2009/05/icam/openid-trust-level1.pdf
>   http//csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-63/SP800-63V1_0_2.pdf
>   },

I heavily suspect this is related to Yahoo having shut down mybloglog a few weeks ago.

Any clue on how to log in with my regular account https://stackoverflow.com/users/16166/laurent-schneider?

My yahoo account is also associated with another OpenID, for example 
https://me.yahoo.com/laurentschneider.

Comment: I'm having the same problem -- my http://flickr.com/user/XYZ openid had been used, but now it generates the exact same error.  I tried disassociating it from https://api.login.yahoo.com/WSLogin/V1/unlink but that seems to have caused me to lose access to my stackoverflow account.

Answer (score 1):

Just to close the loop on this older question: the MyBlogLog service has been closed by Yahoo and is now offline. (Source: [Techrunch](http://techcrunch.com/2011/02/24/yahoo-to-shut-down-mybloglog-on-may-24/) and others.)

Comment: thanks for this answer. Is there any mean to associate http://stackoverflow.com/users/16166/laurent-schneider to me ?